# Some (fake) italic fonts not preserved in Export

Tags: export

For some fonts like DIN Alternate, italics (which I believe are fake since DIN only has one shape) don't get preserved by `Export`

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLabel -> "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"Sine\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\) curve", LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "DIN Alternate"]]
```

[image: Mathematica Output]

```
Export["~/Desktop/out.pdf", %]
Import["~/Desktop/out.pdf", ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: Exported image]

Is there a way to make the exported image match the Mathematica output without rasterizing the whole thing?

Comment: I believe this is an issue with the PDF renderer on your system, as `Import` isn't reloading the  `Graphics` expression but rather the image you'd see with `SystemOpen`. Your best option is to use `ReplaceAll` to fix any invalid `FontFamily` settings so they're supported by your system. If you just want to reload the image as `Graphics`, use `Import[fileName, "PageGraphics"]` to get that (you'll notice with this option the italics are preserved)

Comment: @b3m2a1 `PageGraphics` definitely doesn't change anything for me. I'm confident it's an issue with `Export`, not `Import`. I wish there was an option to convert text to curves when exporting.

Comment: I mean, you can convert the `Text` to curves: ``DiscretizeGraphics[Text[Style["Sine", Italic]], _Text] // Graphics`` and then you can replace all labels. I still think the issue is on the PDF side, especially since you can query the generated PDF and see `DIN Alternate` is embedded as a font